# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 While adding C code to xcode

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, voip

I am compiling C code to Objective C xcode in main class and facing these error with i386 architecture. I have added

- AudioToolBox
- AVFoundation
- Quartz
- MessageUI
- CoreAudio 
  CoreGraphics
  SystemConfiguration

and many other frameworks to the project.
[image: Xcode error image]

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_iaxc_audio_devices_get", referenced from:
      _list_devices in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_call", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
     (maybe you meant: _iaxc_callback)
  "_iaxc_dump_call", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_initialize", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_input_level_get", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_input_level_set", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_millisleep", referenced from:
      _mysleep in MMMain.o
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_output_level_get", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_output_level_set", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_register", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_select_call", referenced from:
      _state_event_callback in MMMain.o
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_send_dtmf", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_set_event_callback", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_set_formats", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_set_silence_threshold", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_shutdown", referenced from:
      _killem in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_start_processing_thread", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_stop_processing_thread", referenced from:
      _main in MMMain.o
  "_iaxc_unregister", referenced from:
      _killem in MMMain.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Ld /Users/umaidsaleem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MiuMiu-hghvoycnydubelcjwabvgeucpndm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MiuMiu.app/MiuMiu normal i386
    cd /Users/umaidsaleem/Desktop/latest_VOIP_testing/miumiu-master_2/iPhone
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/umaidsaleem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MiuMiu-hghvoycnydubelcjwabvgeucpndm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/umaidsaleem/Desktop/latest_VOIP_testing/miumiu-master_1/iPhone -F/Users/umaidsaleem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MiuMiu-hghvoycnydubelcjwabvgeucpndm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/umaidsaleem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MiuMiu-hghvoycnydubelcjwabvgeucpndm/Build/Intermediates/MiuMiu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MiuMiu.build/Objects-normal/i386/MiuMiu.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -llibspeex -llibiax2 -ObjC -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -llibiax2 -llibspeex -framework QuartzCore -framework AVFoundation -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -framework AudioToolbox -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AddressBookUI -framework AddressBook -framework CoreAudio -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/umaidsaleem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MiuMiu-hghvoycnydubelcjwabvgeucpndm/Build/Intermediates/MiuMiu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MiuMiu.build/Objects-normal/i386/MiuMiu_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/umaidsaleem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MiuMiu-hghvoycnydubelcjwabvgeucpndm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MiuMiu.app/MiuMiu
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add the symbols that are actually missing.  However, have a look at the right column of this page, there are many related links as this is apparently a pretty common issue.  Maybe one of the existing questions already describes your exact problem.

Comment: The image is not viewable

Comment: Updated now, image is now visible